# EF entity not set new value to property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have entity class:

```
 public class Account : IAccount
 {
    [Key, ForeignKey("PUser")]
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User PUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
  }
```

But when I try updating retrieve entity and set a new value to property `Balance` the value doesn't change.

Why this happen and how should I change it?

```
Account senderAccount = _context.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IdUser == userSenderId);
if (senderAccount != null)
 senderAccount.Balance = 400;
```

After that `senderAccount.Balance` still have old value

Thnx

Comment: you are missing `_context.SaveChanges();`. Add it after setting balance.

Comment: thats right, my fault seems I tired. ) Thnx

Comment: Oh..Sorry you can put that as an answer @AdilMammadov I have removed my one :D

Comment: @Sampath, thanks, not everyone is kind as you :)

Comment: You're warmly welcome @AdilMammadov :)

Comment: @Sampath, I never saw here such a behavior! impressive!

Comment: Thanks mate @user3378165 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query is not sent to database until `SaveChanges` method is called. So what you have to do, is to add `_context.SaveChanges();` line when you want to send query to database. In your case it should look like this:

```
Account senderAccount = _context.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IdUser == userSenderId);
if (senderAccount != null)
 senderAccount.Balance = 400;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Also, do not forget to crate context inside of `using` block if applicable.
Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: thanks for the help! in my case _context  it's part of repository and dispose with him

Comment: @3axap, you are welcome. Yes, it is better practice. You can search for *entity framework unit of work pattern* for even better one :)